# .net mulitple connection strings impact

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have a .net project with multiple connection strings (around 6 of them) all referencing to the same db.

There're some small differences. Some have different application name, some has different metadata strings which (I believe) references to different generated entities.

What is the impact, if any, to having multiple connection strings to essentially the same db?

Is it better to have separate connection strings for different purposes?
Or is it better to refactor and use only 1 if they're all for 1 application?

Comment: As far as I know, it's just a question of how your code is organized and what you use each one for, as to whether combining them is any advantage; which is probably a very individualized question. At the end of the day, .net sees a connection string as just a variable that you plug in when you want to connect to a db.

Comment: Note that it actually has an impact, for example the [connection pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling) exists for every connection. So you might have a performance impact if you use multiple connections to the same database, because separate physical connections need to be handled and opened.

Comment: The description of the friends is also correct
I also have a suggestion for a study on 'Multiple DbContext'

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you would have a single connection string. As @TimSchmelter pointed out, connection pooling works on a unique connection string.

However, I use two connection strings because of a bug where some settings from transaction connections do not reset. Details of the bug here:

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/96

I use a different connection string for general use and for transactions. The only difference is the "Application Name" property.